# Magnitude and phase of parallel RLC with series resistor

Tags: impedance, passive-networks, math

I have been looking for a while for this issue, but unfortunately I am bit stuck on getting the magnitude as well as the phase of a RLC circuit with a series resistor, seen from V1 (see picture).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi8RxR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am specifically looking for the impedance magnitude (and phase), **not** the transfer function. So in the end I would like to have an expression to directly calculate the impedance as function of a certain frequency. Having the phase response would be nice as well (in degrees)
A very similar issue with just a parallel RLC or series RLC is very well known, however both are a little different (and much easier)

Unfortunately for me it has been like 10-15 years ago that I was active with these kinds of problems, so I'm a bit rusty, lol. So hopefully somebody can help me out here. There have been other posts and topics about similar circuits, but unfortunately none of them contain the magnitude of the impedance.

Anyway, so the complex impedance function can be written as;

$$Z_{V1}=R_{1}+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_{2}}+jwC+\frac{1}{jwL}}$$

To find the magnitude, we know that;
$$\left|Z\right|=\sqrt{R^{2}+X^{2}}$$

And this is basically where is issue starts.
I started with;
$$\left|Z_{V1}\right|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{R_{1}^{2}+\frac{1}{R_{2}^2}+(\frac{1}{wL}-wC)^2}}$$

I used LTSpice to simulate this circuit as a control check, but unfortunately, this expression didn't give the right results.
So I obviously messed up something here?

Comment: The last equation doesn't look right.  I'll spend a few minutes and try to show you where you went wrong.

Comment: Personally, I find it much easier to work with \$s\$ instead of \$j\omega\$. The final result will be a full biquad, and substitution is easy.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
Z_{V_1} &= R_1 + \frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_2} + j \omega C + \frac{1}{j \omega L}} \\
&= R_1 + \frac{j \omega R_2 L}{j \omega L - \omega^2 R_2 CL + R_2} \\
&= \frac{j \omega R_1 L - \omega^2 R_1 R_2 CL + R_1 R_2+ j \omega R_2 L}{j \omega L - \omega^2 R_2 CL + R_2} \\
&= \left( \frac{R_1 R_2 (1 - \omega^2 CL) + j \omega (R_1 + R_2)L}{R_2 (1 - \omega^2 CL)+j \omega L} \right)
\left( \frac{R_2 (1 - \omega^2 CL)-j \omega L}{R_2 (1 - \omega^2 CL)-j \omega L} \right) 
\end{align}
From this point, multiplying the two factors in the denominators gives a real expression.  Multiplying the two factors in the numerators gives four terms, two of which are real and two of which are imaginary.  After summing these, you'll have a complex numerator with two terms and a real denominator.  Now you can use your formula for getting the magnitude without the error you introduced inadvertently.

OK, I saw your note about getting stuck at the next line.  Here's what I get:  a two-term real term and a two-term imaginary term in the numerator and a two-term real denominator.

\begin{align}
        Z_{V_1} &= \frac{R_1 R_2^2 (1 - \omega^2 CL)^2+ \omega^2 L^2 \left( R_1 + R_2 \right)
           + j \left( \omega R_2 (R_1 + R_2) L (1 - \omega^2 CL)-  \omega R_1 R_2 L (1 - \omega^2 CL) \right)}{\left( R_2 (1 - \omega^2 CL) \right)^2 + \omega^2 L^2}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
  \bigl| Z_{V_1} \bigr| &= \frac{
                          \sqrt{
                   \left( R_1 R_2^2 (1 - \omega^2 CL)^2+ \omega^2 L^2 \left( R_1 + R_2 \right)\right)^2
                   + \left( \left( \omega R_2 (R_1 + R_2) L (1 - \omega^2 CL)-  \omega R_1 R_2 L (1 - \omega^2 CL) \right)  \right)^2
} }{\left( R_2 (1 - \omega^2 CL) \right)^2 + \omega^2 L^2}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\angle Z_{V_1} &=  \tan^{-1} \frac{
\left( \omega R_2 (R_1 + R_2) L (1 - \omega^2 CL)-  \omega R_1 R_2 L (1 - \omega^2 CL) \right)}{
R_1 R_2^2 (1 - \omega^2 CL)^2+ \omega^2 L^2 \left( R_1 + R_2 \right)
}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, yeah based on pure experience I was already thinking that just one pesky resistor will make the whole thing a lot more complex.

I am not really following that last part.
After doing the steps I get

$$\frac{{{R}_{1}{R}_{2}{\left({1}-{C}{L}\omega^{2}\right)}+{j}{L}({R}_{1}+{R}_{2})\omega}}{{{R}_{2}{\left({1}-{C}{L}\omega^{2}\right)}+{j}{L}\omega}}\$$

edit; my apologies, but I can't get Latex expression to work in comments apparently...

Comment: @OWC - Just FYI, the Latex you included above was nearly correct - only an erroneous "\" before the final `$` `$` made the syntax wrong, so it was not rendered by the MathJax parser. After removing that, your formula renders as: $$\frac{{{R}_{1}{R}_{2}{\left({1}-{C}{L}\omega^{2}\right)}+{j}{L}({R}_{1}+{R}_{2})\omega}}{{{R}_{2}{\left({1}-{C}{L}\omega^{2}\right)}+{j}{L}\omega}}$$ I hope that's helpful.

Comment: I think the bottom part of |Z| needs a square root as well?

Comment: In the end this is what I got 
$$\left|Z \right|=\frac{\sqrt{(R_1R_2-\omega^2 CLR_1R_2)^2+(\omega L(R_1+R_2))^2}}{\sqrt{(R_2-\omega^2 CLR_2)^2+(\omega L)^2}}$$

This is just the real part I guess?

Comment: No need to take the square root of the denominator as it's a real number, not a complex one. In the numerator you have omitted the square of the imaginary portion. I included it in my edited answer. You need the square root in the numerator because you're summing squared quantities. You've got a square for \$R_1\$ in the numerator that shouldn't be there.

Comment: I just compared your expression against the actual simulated data, but don't get quite the right result, while I do seem to get the right result with the expression in my previous comment? I will double check, since spreadsheets can sometimes be extremely finicky with brackets and such.

Comment: Actually looking back at it, I think the third step isn't needed and seems double maybe?
Basically we can already get the magnitude after everything was multiplied with $$j \omega L - \omega^2 R_2 CL + R_2$$